# Where to use session_write_close(), in ajax

Tags: php, session

My problem is that while an ajax request is going on, the user might click 'contact us' or some other link, but the session is locked, from the ajax, and the user has to wait for that, before being served the next link.

```
main url:
    makes ajax call,
    displays data

ajax target:
    looks at $_SESSION for various reasons,
    calls an api (this will take 5 seconds), 
    makes changes to $_SESSION,
    returns some values
```

During that 5 seconds, user clicks 'contact us'

```
onclick: ajax is aborted, by jquery.
    I dont care, anymore, what the ajax target did.  
    Any changes to SESSION dont matter much, either way.

user has to wait the 5 seconds, then the contact page loads.
```

Where is the proper place to use session_write_close()?  Is it even possible, in this situation? (given that I have to write to SESSION, under normal circumstances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session_start()
looks at $_SESSION for various reasons
  - make copy of values if necessary
session_write_close()
calls an api (this will take 5 seconds), 
session_start()
  - some kind of optimistic lock checks if necessary
makes changes to $_SESSION,
returns some values
```

Comment: firstly, the 'optimistic lock checks'  only one ajax request will be happening at a time (and for the 2 or 3 that occur, only one is long running).  So, I feel pretty optimistic about it ;)

Comment: Next, I see where you restart the session, I take it that this enables me to write to it, again?  And I assume that the session keeps its values, during the time it is closed, yes?

Comment: Oh, wait 'make a copy'  so if I did 
     `$mysess = $_SESSION; `  and then  `$_SESSION= $mysess; ` after session_start(), that would save the session, while closed?

Comment: a) see [optimisitic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control); it's not about you being optimistic, happy or lucky ;-) b) the second session_start() will start the session handling mechanism just like the first: lookup the session id, possibly set headers et al, load data and save data on shutdown. c) I wouldn't copy the whole $_SESSION array (ok, that maybe I would do but:) and then assign a complete array back to $_SESSION. I would copy only those elements that are necessary. The manual only mentions _not_ to use unset() on _SESSION, but anway....

Comment: a) got it, thanks :)  b&c:  I guess I will have to experiment, but it seems to me that making a copy wouldnt be needed, because if $_SESSION['foo']=bar, before you close it, or before php closes it, at the end of the script, when you session_start(), whether it is in mid-script (as this example) or the 'normal' start of the script, would be the same thing?  IOW, the session doesnt go away, just cuz you close it?

Comment: "IOW, the session doesnt go away, just cuz you close it?" - Just like two requests with one session_start() per instance. Another concurrent instance _might_ change the session data inbetween. But if there is no such instance or if it doesn't matter if the session data is changed, you don't have to do anything. I.e. the copy-if-needed thing only applies _if_ you have to take care of consistency yourself.

Comment: No need to copy; session_write_close() does NOT make the $_SESSION variables unavailable. It merely makes them unwriteable.